# Xcode linker error (duplicate symbol), while gcc is working properly

Tags: c, xcode, linker-errors

As the title says, while compiling C-Code in Xcode (tried version 9.4.1 and version 10.0 beta 6) I am getting the following error:

```
Ld /Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Products/Debug/list normal x86_64 (in target: list)
cd /Users/dani/Documents/Prog/Name/list
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13
/Users/dani/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Users/dani/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -L/Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/list.build/Debug/list.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/list.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/list.build/Debug/list.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/list_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/list.build/Debug/list.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/list_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Products/Debug/list

duplicate symbol _students in:
/Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/list.build/Debug/list.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/dani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/list-cqoddyqwcovrpqdkxxcsxeukjgbr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/list.build/Debug/list.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/functions.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When compiling it in terminal with gcc, I am getting no errors and the program is working as intended:

`Daniels-MBP:Test dani$ gcc -Wall main.c functions.c -o prog
Daniels-MBP:Test dani$ ls
functions.c functions.h main.c      prog        view.csv`

The error first showed up when I created an additional **functions.c** and **functions.h** file (so when I only had my **main.c** file I had no issues). Here is the code:

**main.c**

```
#include "functions.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int lineCounter = 0;

    char currentLine[STRINGLEN];

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("view.csv", "r");

    //Namen aus File einlesen

    char *currentValue;

    while(fgets(currentLine, STRINGLEN, fp))
    {
        currentValue = strtok(currentLine, ";");
        strcpy(students[lineCounter].nachname, currentValue);

        currentValue = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(students[lineCounter].vorname, currentValue);

        currentValue = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(students[lineCounter].mtrkNr, currentValue);

        ++lineCounter;
    }

    selectWinner(students, lineCounter);

    return 0;
}
```

**functions.c**

```
#include "functions.h"

void selectWinner (struct student students[ROWS], int lineCounter)
{
    int randomNumber = 0;

    randomNumber = rand() % 45 + 1;

    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));

    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < lineCounter; ++currentIndex)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s", students[currentIndex].vorname, students[currentIndex].nachname, students[currentIndex].mtrkNr);
    }

    printf("The winner is --> %s %s\n", students[randomNumber].vorname, students[randomNumber].nachname);
}
```

**functions.h**

```
#ifndef functions_h
#define functions_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ROWS 50
#define STRINGLEN 40

struct student {
    char nachname[STRINGLEN];
    char vorname[STRINGLEN];
    char mtrkNr[STRINGLEN];
};

struct student students [ROWS];

void selectWinner (struct student students[ROWS], int lineCounter);

#endif /* functions_h */
```

Any suggestions about possible mistakes?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `struct student students[ROWS]` does not belong in a header file (`functions.h`). Given the posted code, it belongs *only* in `main.c`, and only after including `functions.h` (which defines both `student` and `ROWS`). Unrelated, you `selectWinner` is broken. It should be using `lineCounter` as the modulus limit; not the hard-coded 45.

Comment: That solved the linking problem, thank you! The hard-coded 45 was a leftover from the beginning (I also noticed a copy-paste mistake when generating my randomNumber. I called srand after generating my number, so I always got the same value when executing the program multiple times), I sorted it out now. I received a BAD_ACCESS afterwards, but that was just related to me not setting the working directory in Xcode. Works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `struct student students [ROWS];` in functions.h, which is included in both of the .c files, is the cause of the linker error. Instead move that line into one of the two files.

As @WhozCraig mentioned, move that line to the top of main.c and it will compile correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is working now ! :) Appreciate it